# Java : Date String to Hours

Tags: java, java-8, date

i have this Date String `2020-07-26T20:08:27Z` i want to perform date comparison.

so is there any framework/util for this operation.

```
String s1 = "2020-07-26T20:08:27Z";
String s2 = "2020-07-26T21:08:27Z";
```

in the above sample code, i want to find the bigger date

Comment: Use LocalDateTime https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Comment: @swordbeta No, not `LocalDateTime` here. Notice the `Z` on the end. This means UTC. So `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime` classes apply.

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant
.parse( "2020-07-26T20:08:27Z" ) 
.isBefore(
    Instant.parse( "2020-07-26T21:08:27Z" )
)
```

> true

## *java.time*

Use the modern *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

### ISO 8601

The `Z` on the end of your input indicates an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds, or [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu”.

Your input strings are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

### `Instant`

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object represents a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instantA = Instant.parse( "2020-07-26T20:08:27Z" ) ;
Instant instantB = Instant.parse( "2020-07-26T21:08:27Z" ) ;
```

Compare using `equals`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`.

```
boolean aBeforeB = instantA.isBefore( instantB ) ;
```

### `Duration`

You can capture the time elapsed between the two moments as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instantA , instantB ) ;
```

You can ask the `Duration` object if it is zero or negative.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]